# Sending email with scala and play framwork doesn't work on server

Tags: scala, email, playframework

When I try to send a mail with scala and Playmework from localhost with this configuration:

```
play.mailer {
  host=smtp.gmail.com
  port=465
  ssl=true
  user = "emaifortest@gmail.com"
  password = "password"
  debug=false
  mock=false
  from="emaifortest2013@gmail.com"
}
```

and this function which save the user in tempuser collection before sending the mail:

```
  def saveSendConfirmation = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    request.body.validate[TempUserForm.Data].fold(
      form => Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "invalid data"))),
      data => {
        val firstName = data.firstName
        val lastName = data.lastName
        val email = data.email
        val customerId = data.customerId
        val communityId = data.communityId
        val entityId = data.entityId
        val roles = data.roles
        val currentDate: DateTime = new DateTime()
        val user = TempUser(Option(java.util.UUID.randomUUID), firstName, lastName, email, customerId, communityId, entityId, roles, Option(false), currentDate)
        tempUserService.create(user).map {
          case Right(_id) =>
            val email = Email(
              "Verification",
              "<emaifortest2013@gmail.com>",
              Seq(user.email),
              attachments = Seq(),
              bodyText = Some("A text message"),
              bodyHtml = Some(
                """ 
          <a href='http://5.189.165.188:9001/confirmation/""" + _id + """'>
"""))
            mailerClient.send(email)
            Ok(Json.toJson(Json.obj("_id" -> _id)))
          case Left(error) => BadRequest(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> error)))
        }
      })
  }
```

when I test on local or with testProd everything works well but on the server when I try to send the email I get 500 error:

```
! @732jpm95i - Internal server error, for (POST) [/tempuser] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
```

Comment: Nobody can help you without the error stack-trace. But by looking at your code, I thing success/failure in mailer should not have any impact on your response. What mailer are you using ?

Comment: To get the error replace this -> `mailerClient.send(email)` with this -> `Try(mailerClient.send(email)) match { case Success => {  // do nothing } case Failure(ex) => log.error(ex, "failed to send email") }`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh please check the update

Comment: Is this the whole stack-trace obtained after the above mentioned change? I don't think it is.

Comment: So much noise in this question and so little useful information.

Comment: here is the whole error : http://pastebin.com/KrX2810t

Comment: `AuthenticationFailedException` seems pretty explicit. Are you using the correct email credentials?

Comment: yes and it's working on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [whole error log](http://pastebin.com/KrX2810t) shows the answer itself

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 
...
Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
```

You can login from local, so it looks like the google checks the IP or trying to ask the second step in the process of authentification. You need to read https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

I have the similar scenario and use "[less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)" option in google account, so I can send email from local and from a server.